# Make photo cover full area in hexagon shape

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-shapes

I have a vertical image in a hexagon responsive grid and I would like to blow it up so that the image doesn't have space on the left and right sides (shown in my code).

If someone could help me with this, that would be great as I have been having troubles trying to use both vertical and horizontal images in my grid and when coming upon vertical images, having issues getting it to fill the full hexagon without gaps on each side.

```css
#grid {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 2% auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-size: 15px;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.hexagon {
  position: relative;
  visibility: hidden;
  outline: 1px solid transparent;
}

.hexagon::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  padding-bottom: 86.602%;
}

.inside {
  position: absolute;
  width: 96%;
  padding-bottom: 110.851%;
  margin: 0 2%;
  overflow: hidden;
  visibility: hidden;
  outline: 1px solid transparent;
  -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, -60deg) skewY(30deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, -60deg) skewY(30deg);
  transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, -60deg) skewY(30deg);
}

.inside * {
  position: absolute;
  visibility: visible;
  outline: 1px solid transparent;
}

.link {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: gray;
  -webkit-transform: skewY(-30deg) rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 60deg);
  -ms-transform: skewY(-30deg) rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 60deg);
  transform: skewY(-30deg) rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 60deg);
}

.hexagon img {
  left: -100%;
  right: -100%;
  width: auto;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 0, 0deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 0, 0deg);
  transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 0, 0deg);
}

.inner-content {
  top: 49%;
  left: 49%;
  transform: translate(-49%, -49%);
}

.hexagon h1,
.hexagon p {
  position: relative;
  white-space: normal;
  color: white;
}

.hexagon h1 {
  font-size: 1.4em;
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px #000;
}

.hexagon h1::after {
  position: relative;
  left: 45%;
  width: 10%;
  text-align: center;
}


/* sizing and row indents */

@media (min-width:1201px) {
  #grid {
    padding-bottom: 4.4%
  }
  .hexagon {
    width: 20%;
  }
  .hexagon:nth-child(9n+6) {
    margin-left: 10%;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 1200px) and (min-width:901px) {
  #grid {
    padding-bottom: 5.5%
  }
  .hexagon {
    width: 25%;
  }
  .hexagon:nth-child(7n+5) {
    margin-left: 12.5%;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 900px) and (min-width:601px) {
  #grid {
    padding-bottom: 7.4%
  }
  .hexagon {
    width: 33.333%;
  }
  .hexagon:nth-child(5n+4) {
    margin-left: 16.666%;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
  #grid {
    padding-bottom: 11.2%
  }
  .hexagon {
    width: 50%;
  }
  .hexagon:nth-child(3n+3) {
    margin-left: 25%;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 400px) {
  #grid {
    font-size: 13px;
  }
}
```

```html
<ul id="grid">

  <li class="hexagon">
    <div class="inside">
      <a class="link" href="">
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/01/Flatiron_Building_3618433845_5745ebc1b9.jpg/220px-Flatiron_Building_3618433845_5745ebc1b9.jpg" alt="" />
        <div class="inner-content">
          <h1>title</h1>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="hexagon">
    <div class="inside">
      <a class="link" href="">
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/01/Flatiron_Building_3618433845_5745ebc1b9.jpg/220px-Flatiron_Building_3618433845_5745ebc1b9.jpg" alt="" />
        <div class="inner-content">
          <h1>title</h1>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="hexagon">
    <div class="inside">
      <a class="link" href="">
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/01/Flatiron_Building_3618433845_5745ebc1b9.jpg/220px-Flatiron_Building_3618433845_5745ebc1b9.jpg" alt="" />
        <div class="inner-content">
          <h1>title</h1>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="hexagon">
    <div class="inside">
      <a class="link" href="">
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/01/Flatiron_Building_3618433845_5745ebc1b9.jpg/220px-Flatiron_Building_3618433845_5745ebc1b9.jpg" alt="" />
        <div class="inner-content">
          <h1>title</h1>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="hexagon">
    <div class="inside">
      <a class="link" href="">
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/01/Flatiron_Building_3618433845_5745ebc1b9.jpg/220px-Flatiron_Building_3618433845_5745ebc1b9.jpg" alt="" />
        <div class="inner-content">
          <h1>title</h1>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="hexagon">
    <div class="inside">
      <a class="link" href="">
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/01/Flatiron_Building_3618433845_5745ebc1b9.jpg/220px-Flatiron_Building_3618433845_5745ebc1b9.jpg" alt="" />
        <div class="inner-content">
          <h1>title</h1>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="hexagon">
    <div class="inside">
      <a class="link" href="">
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/01/Flatiron_Building_3618433845_5745ebc1b9.jpg/220px-Flatiron_Building_3618433845_5745ebc1b9.jpg" alt="" />
        <div class="inner-content">
          <h1>title</h1>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="hexagon">
    <div class="inside">
      <a class="link" href="">
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/01/Flatiron_Building_3618433845_5745ebc1b9.jpg/220px-Flatiron_Building_3618433845_5745ebc1b9.jpg" alt="" />
        <div class="inner-content">
          <h1>title</h1>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="hexagon">
    <div class="inside">
      <a class="link" href="">
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/01/Flatiron_Building_3618433845_5745ebc1b9.jpg/220px-Flatiron_Building_3618433845_5745ebc1b9.jpg" alt="" />
        <div class="inner-content">
          <h1>title</h1>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </li>

</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of giving the images `width: auto` and `height: 100%`...

```
.hexagon img {
  left: -100%;
  right: -100%;
  width: auto;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  transform: rotate3d(0,0,0,0deg);
}
```

Do the reverse, `width: 100%` and `height: auto`...

```
.hexagon img {
  left: -100%;
  right: -100%;
  width: 100%;  /* adjustment */
  height: auto; /* adjustment */
  margin: 0 auto;
  transform: rotate3d(0,0,0,0deg);
}
```

```css
#grid {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 2% auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-size: 15px;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.hexagon {
  position: relative;
  visibility: hidden;
  outline: 1px solid transparent;
}

.hexagon::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  padding-bottom: 86.602%;
}

.inside {
  position: absolute;
  width: 96%;
  padding-bottom: 110.851%;
  margin: 0 2%;
  overflow: hidden;
  visibility: hidden;
  outline: 1px solid transparent;
  -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, -60deg) skewY(30deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, -60deg) skewY(30deg);
  transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, -60deg) skewY(30deg);
}

.inside * {
  position: absolute;
  visibility: visible;
  outline: 1px solid transparent;
}

.link {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: gray;
  -webkit-transform: skewY(-30deg) rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 60deg);
  -ms-transform: skewY(-30deg) rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 60deg);
  transform: skewY(-30deg) rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 60deg);
}

.hexagon img {
  left: -100%;
  right: -100%;
  width: 100%; /* adjustment */
  height: auto; /* adjustment */
  margin: 0 auto;
  -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 0, 0deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 0, 0deg);
  transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 0, 0deg);
}

.inner-content {
  top: 49%;
  left: 49%;
  transform: translate(-49%, -49%);
}

.hexagon h1,
.hexagon p {
  position: relative;
  white-space: normal;
  color: white;
}

.hexagon h1 {
  font-size: 1.4em;
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px #000;
}

.hexagon h1::after {
  position: relative;
  left: 45%;
  width: 10%;
  text-align: center;
}


/* sizing and row indents */

@media (min-width:1201px) {
  #grid {
    padding-bottom: 4.4%
  }
  .hexagon {
    width: 20%;
  }
  .hexagon:nth-child(9n+6) {
    margin-left: 10%;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 1200px) and (min-width:901px) {
  #grid {
    padding-bottom: 5.5%
  }
  .hexagon {
    width: 25%;
  }
  .hexagon:nth-child(7n+5) {
    margin-left: 12.5%;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 900px) and (min-width:601px) {
  #grid {
    padding-bottom: 7.4%
  }
  .hexagon {
    width: 33.333%;
  }
  .hexagon:nth-child(5n+4) {
    margin-left: 16.666%;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
  #grid {
    padding-bottom: 11.2%
  }
  .hexagon {
    width: 50%;
  }
  .hexagon:nth-child(3n+3) {
    margin-left: 25%;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 400px) {
  #grid {
    font-size: 13px;
  }
}
```

```html
<ul id="grid">

  <li class="hexagon">
    <div class="inside">
      <a class="link" href="">
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/01/Flatiron_Building_3618433845_5745ebc1b9.jpg/220px-Flatiron_Building_3618433845_5745ebc1b9.jpg" alt="" />
        <div class="inner-content">
          <h1>title</h1>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="hexagon">
    <div class="inside">
      <a class="link" href="">
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/01/Flatiron_Building_3618433845_5745ebc1b9.jpg/220px-Flatiron_Building_3618433845_5745ebc1b9.jpg" alt="" />
        <div class="inner-content">
          <h1>title</h1>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="hexagon">
    <div class="inside">
      <a class="link" href="">
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/01/Flatiron_Building_3618433845_5745ebc1b9.jpg/220px-Flatiron_Building_3618433845_5745ebc1b9.jpg" alt="" />
        <div class="inner-content">
          <h1>title</h1>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="hexagon">
    <div class="inside">
      <a class="link" href="">
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/01/Flatiron_Building_3618433845_5745ebc1b9.jpg/220px-Flatiron_Building_3618433845_5745ebc1b9.jpg" alt="" />
        <div class="inner-content">
          <h1>title</h1>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="hexagon">
    <div class="inside">
      <a class="link" href="">
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/01/Flatiron_Building_3618433845_5745ebc1b9.jpg/220px-Flatiron_Building_3618433845_5745ebc1b9.jpg" alt="" />
        <div class="inner-content">
          <h1>title</h1>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="hexagon">
    <div class="inside">
      <a class="link" href="">
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/01/Flatiron_Building_3618433845_5745ebc1b9.jpg/220px-Flatiron_Building_3618433845_5745ebc1b9.jpg" alt="" />
        <div class="inner-content">
          <h1>title</h1>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="hexagon">
    <div class="inside">
      <a class="link" href="">
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/01/Flatiron_Building_3618433845_5745ebc1b9.jpg/220px-Flatiron_Building_3618433845_5745ebc1b9.jpg" alt="" />
        <div class="inner-content">
          <h1>title</h1>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="hexagon">
    <div class="inside">
      <a class="link" href="">
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/01/Flatiron_Building_3618433845_5745ebc1b9.jpg/220px-Flatiron_Building_3618433845_5745ebc1b9.jpg" alt="" />
        <div class="inner-content">
          <h1>title</h1>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="hexagon">
    <div class="inside">
      <a class="link" href="">
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/01/Flatiron_Building_3618433845_5745ebc1b9.jpg/220px-Flatiron_Building_3618433845_5745ebc1b9.jpg" alt="" />
        <div class="inner-content">
          <h1>title</h1>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </li>

</ul>
```